# Не работает clear у matplotlib FigureCanvasQTAgg

Tags: python, pyqt5, matplotlib

метод `self.ui.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(self.x_axis, self.y_axis)` работает отлично, а вот при использовании `self.ui.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()` ничего не происходит

main.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from design import Ui_MainWindow
from calc_data_c import calc
import sys


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x_axis = []
        self.y_axis = []
        self.n = 0
        self.delta_coils = 0
        self.q = 0
        self.delta_rings = 0
        self.z = 1
        self.delta_areas = 0
        self.dx = 0

        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.ui.MplWidget.canvas, self))

        self.ui.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.n_changed)
        self.ui.doubleSpinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.delta_coils_changed)
        self.ui.horizontalSlider_2.valueChanged.connect(self.q_changed)
        self.ui.doubleSpinBox_3.valueChanged.connect(self.delta_rings_changed)
        self.ui.horizontalSlider_3.valueChanged.connect(self.z_changed)
        self.ui.doubleSpinBox_2.valueChanged.connect(self.delta_areas_changed)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_calc_clicked)
        self.ui.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.dx_changed)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.btn_clear_clicked)

    def n_changed(self):
        self.n = self.ui.horizontalSlider.value()
        self.ui.label.setText(str(self.n))

    def delta_coils_changed(self):
        self.delta_coils = self.ui.doubleSpinBox.value() / 1000

    def q_changed(self):
        self.q = self.ui.horizontalSlider_2.value()
        self.ui.label_5.setText(str(self.q))

    def delta_rings_changed(self):
        self.delta_rings = self.ui.doubleSpinBox_3.value() / 1000

    def z_changed(self):
        self.z = self.ui.horizontalSlider_3.value()
        self.ui.label_8.setText(str(self.z))

    def delta_areas_changed(self):
        self.delta_areas = self.ui.doubleSpinBox_2.value() / 100

    def btn_calc_clicked(self):
        self.x_axis, self.y_axis = calc(self.delta_coils, self.delta_rings, self.delta_areas, self.n, self.q, self.z, self.dx)
        self.ui.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(self.x_axis, self.y_axis)
        self.ui.MplWidget.canvas.draw()

    def dx_changed(self):
        self.dx = int(self.ui.spinBox.value())

    def btn_clear_clicked(self):
        self.ui.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = Window()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

mplwidget.py имеет такую структуру:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MplWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

design.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1717, 845)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 650, 191, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 20, 81, 61))
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 160, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider.setMinimum(1)
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(24)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 161, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 130, 191, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalSlider_2 = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 160, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider_2.setObjectName("horizontalSlider_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(34, 210, 161, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 190, 55, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 280, 201, 20))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.doubleSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.doubleSpinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 161, 22))
        self.doubleSpinBox.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 430, 211, 20))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 320, 81, 61))
        self.label_8.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 360, 161, 16))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalSlider_3 = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 340, 160, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider_3.setMinimum(1)
        self.horizontalSlider_3.setMaximum(24)
        self.horizontalSlider_3.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider_3.setObjectName("horizontalSlider_3")
        self.doubleSpinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.doubleSpinBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 410, 161, 22))
        self.doubleSpinBox_2.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox_2")
        self.doubleSpinBox_3 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.doubleSpinBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 260, 161, 22))
        self.doubleSpinBox_3.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox_3")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(44, 500, 161, 20))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 470, 31, 21))
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 580, 191, 61))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 470, 161, 22))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.MplWidget = MplWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.MplWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 10, 1431, 781))
        self.MplWidget.setObjectName("MplWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1717, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Посчитать значения"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "кол-во витков (>0)"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "расстояние между витками(мм)"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "кол-во колец(>0)"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "расстояние между кольцами(мм)"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "расстояние между областями(мм)"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "кол-во областей (>0)"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "dx(10e-k)"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "  k = "))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистить систему координат"))
from mplwidget import MplWidget
```

Answer (score 1):

после стирания нужно отрисовать canvas, чтобы увидеть изменения.

```
self.ui.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()
self.ui.MplWidget.canvas.draw()
```